# Modeling physical processes with PDE or Machine Learning Techniques

Tags: partial-differential-equations, machine-learning, mathematical-modeling

My very naive view on approaches to mathematical modeling is that historically differential equations and in particular partial differential equations have been used with great success to model processes from physics to economics. With the advent of higher power computers, machine learning techniques seem to now be a popular option in modeling these types of things as well.

When do machine learning techniques fall short of what PDE/DE can produce in terms of an accurate model? If I was given a ton of data to train my model, would machine learning techniques be the clear cut winner every time or do DE/PDE sometimes prove more effective even when data is plentiful?

Comment: If things are predictable, you can build a machine learning model that can capture the pattern. The issue is interpretability. We don’t just want to predict, we want to understand. This is not to say machine learning is useless in physics... it can be great for finding patterns / separating signal from noise and new use cases have been appearing rapidly.

Comment: It would seem that [machine learning is already beating direct modelling in chaotic systems](https://www.quantamagazine.org/machine-learnings-amazing-ability-to-predict-chaos-20180418/). However, in addition to what spaceisdarkgreen stated, it is still unknown _how and why_ [machine learning works so well](https://www.quantamagazine.org/been-kim-is-building-a-translator-for-artificial-intelligence-20190110/).

Comment: echoing @spaceisdarkgreen sentiment slightly differently, the distinction is not unlike that of correlation and causation ... machine learning can help understand how dataset elements relate to one another, but cannot provide the causative description capturing the "why"'s